# Change button's drawableLeft when the button is clicked

Tags: android, button, onclick, android-drawable, xml-drawable

I have a `Button` with a `drawableLeft`and when i click on it i want to change only the `drawableleft` for another image. What java code i have to use?

`XML`:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/docli_btn_apagar"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:onClick="ApagarLinha"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/trash"
    android:text="@string/apagar" 
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
```

Comment: Come on, you can come up with a bit of code of your own, no?

Comment: you mean on press different image and when you release button back to original drawable,right?

Comment: no Pratik, after clicked i want the image to change

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would be called in your button's `onClick()` handler

```
// get your button
Button docli_btn_apagar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.docli_btn_apagar );

// get the drawable
Drawable img = getContext().getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.smiley );

// set the drawable left
docli_btn_apagar.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( img, null, null, null );
```

Or alternatively:

```
// You can skip the drawable object directly, by using ints/IDs
docli_btn_apagar.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.smiley, 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class AsyncClassTest extends Activity {

String strMessage;
private Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.docli_btn_apagar);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ((Button) view).setCompoundDrawables(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.btn_plus), null, null, null);
        }
    });
}
}
```